# Cannot redirect after logout

Tags: angularjs, url, redirect

I have a menu, a couple of links actually that are all controlled by an angular controller. Inside that controller, when the "Logout" link is clicked I have

```
$scope.logout = function () {
      //no animation when changing pages
      $rootScope.animation = "";

      //delete user form factory
      myFactory.isLogged = false;
      delete myFactory.user;           

      //remove data user from coockies
      localStorageService.remove("user");

      $location.path("/");  

 }
```

My urls are like `http://localhost:8383/#/`

but this `$location.path("/");`  redirects to this `http://localhost:8383/#` and I get only the header and the footer, and no page content.

I also tried `$location.path("#/");` , `$location.path("/#/");` but nothing.

I run this in the server that netbeans has embedded.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: `$location.path("/")` should work..what is happening in browser URL bar while you are doing `$location.path("/")` ?

Comment: @PankajParkar What do you mean "what is happening while you are doing it" ? What should I check?

Comment: look at updated comment

Comment: you could also try url() see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: @PankajParkar In the URL bar I see `http://localhost:8383/#` instead of `http://localhost:8383/#/` . I get no errors in my console.

Comment: @FelixMelix Thanks, but there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho its still a mystery to me, why it didnt worked with just the `$location`,

I used `$window.location.href = "/";` and it worked right away.

If anybody knows why it didnt worked with `$location`, please explain. Thanks